# Have Xcode highlight operator overloads

Tags: swift, xcode, themes

I'd like to use a set of arithmetic operator overloads (+,-,*,/) and I noticed that because they are user defined functions, Xcode color codes them differently than the default operators, which is a really nice visual reminder that the operators are doing implicit conversions. However, I'd like to make this coloring even more prominent and unique from the color coding of other non-operator functions. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know there is only one solution:

You can change the color in Xcode Preferences "Fonts & Colors" by changing the "Project Function and Method Names".

[image]

Then every function and operator will change it's color.

[image]

There is no way to change the color of the operator only, because it's a normal function.